# How to pass id of an element to a .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and i have found out how to translate its UI into Spanish. Since i don't want to call this translation code everytime i create a view that will use dataTables, i have decided to store the following code into a separate .js file:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "language":{
            "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
            "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
            "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "search" : "Búsqueda",
            "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
            "Processing": "Procesando...",
            "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
            "paginate": {
                "previous": "Anterior",
                "next": "Siguiente", 
                }
        }
    });
} );
```

Then I would call this file by using the javascript tag as follows:

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/dataTables.MX_es.js')}}"></script>
```

I don't know how i would pass the related identifier *#table_id* to this call of my .js file.

A temporary solution i've got by now is to have this identifier as fixed (#table_id) ...
But what would I do if I had to use more than one dataTable inside a view?

That's why I need to pass the id as variable and the .js file should catch it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1:**
Declare a global variable for id of the datatable and use it in your script file, this would work for one datatable only, you could however use an array of ids declared globally and iterate over them in your .js file and call your routine for every id if you want this to work for more than one datatable. Using global variable is however not encouraged, but this would do the trick.

```
<script> var myGlobalPlaceholder = "#myDatatable"; </script>
<script src="{{URL::asset('DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/dataTables.MX_es.js')}}"></script>
```

**SOLUTION 2:** 
Since you need to do this for more than one datatable on a single page why don't you place the following code inside a separate .js file lets say `initializer.js`:

```
//File: initializer.js:
    var spanishDatatableInitializer =function(table_id)
    {
        $(table).DataTable({
                "language":{
                    "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
                    "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
                    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "search" : "Búsqueda",
                    "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
                    "Processing": "Procesando...",
                    "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "Anterior",
                        "next": "Siguiente", 
                        }
                }
            });
    }
```

And then include it in your View file like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="initializer.js"></script>
```

And for that page's specific .js file call that function for every datatable id that is in your view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   spanishDatatableInitializer("#tableId1");
   spanishDatatableInitializer("#tableId2");
})
```

**SOLUTION 3:**
As azium suggested, use a common prefixed name for your datatable ids like `"#my_datatable_*******"` and in your js file do this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var dataTables = [];

$("div[id^='#my_datatable_']").each(function(){
  // dataTables.push(this.id);  // only for testing
$(this.id).DataTable({
        "language":{
            "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
            "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
            "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "search" : "Búsqueda",
            "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
            "Processing": "Procesando...",
            "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
            "paginate": {
                "previous": "Anterior",
                "next": "Siguiente", 
                }
        }
    });
});  
} );
```

Comment: In solution 3, you don't need to call `each()`. When you call `jQuery(<selector>)` it returns an array of objects where the chained function get the context of each of them. Same reason you don't need to write `$('.boxes').each($(this).hide())` to hide every matched element.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is how do YOU know which element to pass to your `DataTable` function. Consider the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(someVariable).DataTables({ ... })
})
```

You will have to do one of two things. Pass the name of the `id` you want through the `src=".."` as you suggested (not going to work), or you will have to modify `someVariable`. In both instances you have to manually tell the code which element you want, so you're not really saving yourself much work.

What you could do, is follow some sort of naming convention, so that your function will always match a set of selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[id^="data-table-"]').DataTables({ ... })
})
```

This way as long as your tables always start with 'data-table-' like:

```
id="data-table-something-something"
```

your function will run without having to hard-code the ID (or multiple ID's) everytime.